# Infinite "for" loop in "show_ads_impl_fy2021.js" from google AdSense

Tags: javascript, adsense

I added Google AdSense script to my site in the header according to Google's tutorial. After some time, I found an issue in `show_ads_impl_fy2021.js` file loaded by this script while scrolling page.

```
function VB(a, b) {
    const c = a.innerWidth
      , d = a.innerHeight;
    let e = d;
    for (; e > b; ) {
        var f = Mu({
            ec: 0,
            Hb: c,
            Vb: 9,
            hc: e - b,
            Ib: e,
            Wb: 9
        });
        f = Ou(TB(a), f);
        if (!f)
            return d - e;
        e = f.getBoundingClientRect().top - 1
    }
    return null
}
```

[image]
In my case, `e` variable is always more than `b` variable. So, we get infinite `for` loop.

Any ideas how it can be fixed?!

PS. screenshot of files
[image]

Also, I've found out it's because of `Anchor ads` on the page. If I turn off this ad, the issue goes out.

Comment: Thank you for providing the actual function that is causing the issue. Can you also provide the version of show_ads_impl? It's in the file URL. This will help to identify the original unobfuscated function. And do you have public URL to your page?

Comment: [this is our public page](https://go4trans.com/01m-01n-01p-096-097-098-bushing-kit-clutch-failure-delayed-reverse-low-clutch-oil-pressure-low-line-pressure-shudder-shifts-flare-shifts/) @MikitaBelahlazau

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I wasn't able to reproduce it on your page. But was able to find the underlying function that is causing it. We are working on a fix.

Comment: Great! You can reproduce it by scrolling down and up while refreshing the page with `anchor ad`.

Comment: Late update, but this bug should have been fixed.

Comment: Confirm, it's not reproducing now.